# Atomic time and System time difference on EC2 instance

Tags: java, linux, amazon-ec2

I have Java web application deployed on Tomcat on Amazon EC2 instance. It uses OpenID authentication for users login. It's running for 8-9 months now. However, when ec2 instance is running for more than month, users are not able to login anymore. The reason is that OpenID verification include comparison of time when response has been sent from OpenID provider and local time which should not be more than 60 seconds.

However, my EC2 instance got wrong system time. I configured it to synchronise system time each time I restart instance, but over the time it goes ahead of atomic time. For example, I restarted server 15 days ago,and today, it goes 27 seconds ahead.

Did anyone experience this problem? Is there any solution, other then restarting server once in a while?

Thanks,

Zoran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual machines by its nature can cause time difference from the host over a period of time. Its one of the most common problems in virtual machines.

There are several solutions, the first thing i would try is *** use NTP server *** to sync time. It should help you in this case

http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/Timekeeping-In-VirtualMachines.pdf this white paper by vmware discusses other possible solutions but i would start with NTP server if you don't have one already.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I just installed NTP and it seems that it works. I'll follow that next days.